# facebook graph api for poste is not show all data in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

i am working one facebook intrgation project in ios,iphone 
so i am using **me?fields=posts** on browser is working properly 
i means on this link developer account 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dposts

but when i am using  **me?fields=posts** in xcode this only return a old data not all data 
here is my code so please give me solution where i am doing mistake

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=posts"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if (!error) {
                             NSLog(@"Results: %@", result);
                              NSArray *post = [result valueForKey:@"posts"];
                              NSArray *mainData = [post valueForKey:@"data"];
                             /// NSLog(@"Results: show image>>>>>>> %@", [mainData valueForKey:@"picture"]);

                               //
                              NSArray *picturedata =[mainData valueForKey:@"picture"];

                              NSLog(@"%@",picturedata);
```

Here i attacha a image link also please check

[image 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b8h2677gwam9j8p/Screen%20Shot%202014-04-26%20at%206.58.25%20PM.png)

in Graph api data is

```
{
  "posts": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "100005440749818_240650716126285", 
        "from": {
          "name": "Birjesh Sharma", 
          "id": "100005440749818"
        }, 
        "message": "Hello\r\n\r\n\r\n", 
        "picture": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/app_full_proxy.php?app=278318608948142&v=1&size=z&cksum=9c977855a08e5bde268444a1ab24a254&src=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.github.com%2Ffbsamples%2Fios-3.x-howtos%2Fmaster%2FImages%2Fiossdk_logo.png", 
        "link": "https://developers.facebook.com/ios", 
        "name": "Facebook SDK for iOS", 
        "caption": "Build great social apps and get more installs.", 
        "description": "The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", 
        "icon": "https://www.facebook.com/images/litestand/bookmarks/sidebar/icons/small/icon-app.png", 
        "actions": [
          {
            "name": "Comment", 
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/100005440749818/posts/240650716126285"
          }, 
          {
            "name": "Like", 
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/100005440749818/posts/240650716126285"
          }
        ], 
        "privacy": {
          "description": "Friends", 
          "value": "ALL_FRIENDS", 
          "friends": "", 
          "networks": "", 
          "allow": "", 
          "deny": ""
        }, 
        "type": "link", 
        "status_type": "app_created_story", 
        "application": {
          "name": "Feed Dialog How To", 
          "id": "278318608948142"
        }, 
        "created_time": "2014-04-26T12:59:15+0000", 
        "updated_time": "2014-04-26T12:59:15+0000"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "100005440749818_240650712792952", 
        "from": {
          "name": "Birjesh Sharma", 
          "id": "100005440749818"
        }, 
        "message": "Hello\r\n\r\n\r\n", 
        "picture": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/app_full_proxy.php?app=278318608948142&v=1&size=z&cksum=9c977855a08e5bde268444a1ab24a254&src=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.github.com%2Ffbsamples%2Fios-3.x-howtos%2Fmaster%2FImages%2Fiossdk_logo.png", 
        "link": "https://developers.facebook.com/ios", 
        "name": "Facebook SDK for iOS", 
        "caption": "Build great social apps and get more installs.", 
        "description": "The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", 
        "icon": "https://www.facebook.com/images/litestand/bookmarks/sidebar/icons/small/icon-app.png", 
        "actions": [
          {
            "name": "Comment", 
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/100005440749818/posts/240650712792952"
          }, 
          {
            "name": "Like", 
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/100005440749818/posts/240650712792952"
          }
        ], 
        "privacy": {
          "description": "Friends", 
          "value": "ALL_FRIENDS", 
          "friends": "", 
          "networks": "", 
          "allow": "", 
          "deny": ""
        }, 
        "type": "link", 
        "status_type": "app_created_story", 
        "application": {
          "name": "Feed Dialog How To", 
          "id": "278318608948142"
        }, 
        "created_time": "2014-04-26T12:59:14+0000", 
        "updated_time": "2014-04-26T12:59:14+0000"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "100005440749818_240643612793662", 
        "from": {
          "name": "Birjesh Sharma", 
          "id": "100005440749818"
        }, 
        "message": "Hello how are you", 
        "actions": [
          {
            "name": "Comment", 
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/100005440749818/posts/240643612793662"
          }, 
          {
            "name": "Like", 
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/100005440749818/posts/240643612793662"
          }
        ], 
        "privacy": {
          "description": "Friends", 
          "value": "ALL_FRIENDS", 
          "friends": "", 
          "networks": "", 
          "allow": "", 
          "deny": ""
        }, 
        "type": "status", 
        "status_type": "mobile_status_update", 
        "application": {
          "name": "Batch Requests How To", 
          "id": "216458921816803"
        }, 
        "created_time": "2014-04-26T12:20:43+0000", 
        "updated_time": "2014-04-26T12:20:43+0000"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "100005440749818_240368252821198", 
        "from": {
          "name": "Birjesh Sharma", 
          "id": "100005440749818"
        }, 
        "story": "Birjesh Sharma added a new photo.", 
        "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-0/10155869_240368246154532_637168545169195821_s.jpg", 
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=240368246154532&set=a.170520606472630.1073741830.100005440749818&type=1&relevant_count=1", 
        "name": "HelloFBSample Photos", 
        "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif", 
        "actions": [
          {
            "name": "Comment", 
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/100005440749818/posts/240368252821198"
          }, 
          {
            "name": "Like", 
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/100005440749818/posts/240368252821198"
          }
        ], 
        "privacy": {
          "description": "Only Me", 
          "value": "SELF", 
          "friends": "", 
          "networks": "", 
          "allow": "", 
          "deny": ""
        }, 
        "type": "photo", 
        "status_type": "added_photos", 
        "object_id": "240368246154532", 
        "application": {
          "name": "HelloFBSample", 
          "namespace": "fbsdktemplateapp", 
          "id": "355198514515820"
        }, 
        "created_time": "2014-04-25T13:26:06+0000", 
        "updated_time": "2014-04-25T13:26:06+0000"
      }, 
      {
        "id": "100005440749818_240333912824632", 
        "from": {
          "name": "Birjesh Sharma", 
          "id": "100005440749818"
        }, 
        "message": "Post by nishant", 
        "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-0/10155899_240333846157972_3108893745639530212_s.jpg", 
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=240333846157972&set=a.239581289566561.1073741833.100005440749818&type=1&relevant_count=1", 
        "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif", 
        "actions": [
          {
            "name": "Comment", 
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/100005440749818/posts/240333912824632"
          }, 
          {
            "name": "Like", 
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/100005440749818/posts/240333912824632"
          }
        ], 
        "privacy": {
          "description": "Public", 
          "value": "EVERYONE", 
          "friends": "", 
          "networks": "", 
          "allow": "", 
          "deny": ""
        }, 
        "type": "photo", 
        "status_type": "added_photos", 
        "object_id": "240333846157972", 
        "created_time": "2014-04-25T10:33:45+0000", 
        "updated_time": "2014-04-25T10:33:45+0000", 
        "likes": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": "100005440749818", 
              "name": "Birjesh Sharma"
            }
          ], 
          "paging": {
            "cursors": {
              "after": "MTAwMDA1NDQwNzQ5ODE4", 
              "before": "MTAwMDA1NDQwNzQ5ODE4"
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

and when i am using this graph api in xcode the data show this

```
Results: {
    id = 100005440749818;
    posts =     {
        data =         (
                        {
                "created_time" = "2014-04-17T14:13:12+0000";
                from =                 {
                    id = 100005440749818;
                    name = "Birjesh Sharma";
                };
                id = "100005440749818_238353183022705";
                link = "https://www.facebook.com/nitin.dhiran.1?fref=nf_fr";
                picture = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t1.0-1/c0.9.50.50/p50x50/10262125_697172320343788_6250762651875413687_t.jpg";
                privacy =                 {
                    value = "";
                };
                "status_type" = "approved_friend";
                story = "Birjesh Sharma is now friends with Nitin Dhiran and 3 other people.";
                "story_tags" =                 {
                    0 =                     (
                                                {
                            id = 100005440749818;
                            length = 14;
                            name = "Birjesh Sharma";
                            offset = 0;
                            type = user;
                        }
                    );
                    35 =                     (
                                                {
                            id = 100001530793389;
                            length = 12;
                            name = "Nitin Dhiran";
                            offset = 35;
                            type = user;
                        }
                    );
                    52 =                     (
                                                {
                            id = 100008058972523;
                            length = 14;
                            name = "Hemant Kumar";
                            offset = 52;
                            type = user;
                        },
                                                {
                            id = 100001307401657;
                            length = 14;
                            name = "Chetan Pushpad";
                            offset = 52;
                            type = user;
                        },
                                                {
                            id = 100002675972915;
                            length = 14;
                            name = "Vipin Shukla";
                            offset = 52;
                            type = user;
                        }
                    );
                };
                type = link;
                "updated_time" = "2014-04-17T14:13:12+0000";
            },
                        {
                "created_time" = "2014-03-27T07:21:35+0000";
                from =                 {
                    id = 100005440749818;
                    name = "Birjesh Sharma";
                };
                id = "100005440749818_232528183605205";
                privacy =                 {
                    value = "";
                };
                "status_type" = "approved_friend";
                story = "Birjesh Sharma is now friends with Ishant Tiwari and Viraj Dongre.";
                "story_tags" =                 {
                    0 =                     (
                                                {
                            id = 100005440749818;
                            length = 14;
                            name = "Birjesh Sharma";
                            offset = 0;
                            type = user;
                        }
                    );
                    35 =                     (
                                                {
                            id = 100000329153640;
                            length = 13;
                            name = "Ishant Tiwari";
                            offset = 35;
                            type = user;
                        }
                    );
                    53 =                     (
                                                {
                            id = 100002123975517;
                            length = 12;
                            name = "Viraj Dongre";
                            offset = 53;
                            type = user;
                        }
                    );
                };
                type = status;
                "updated_time" = "2014-03-27T07:21:35+0000";
            }
        );
        paging =         {
            next = "https://graph.facebook.com/100005440749818/posts?access_token=CAAUTJQ2n428BAN3p9kiFFMZA7ZBlDO2NTIddfkUNJdbqT32kfbVs8GJaORmJXTF4NnF6RUtIwwp0H0vTzS147lxFF3runTHbupqZBkxbyl73dV5URHwvZA78CqVXWJggaofAy2JfZBf1GCoUQfNCyN0TAJaEnnsLn9ea6d2wLtDAataFtxGyFQJwZBWajQOiIwtidXqliCFV8haorHgfE4ahdbpO5n7oUZD&limit=25&until=1395904894";
            previous = "https://graph.facebook.com/100005440749818/posts?access_token=CAAUTJQ2n428BAN3p9kiFFMZA7ZBlDO2NTIddfkUNJdbqT32kfbVs8GJaORmJXTF4NnF6RUtIwwp0H0vTzS147lxFF3runTHbupqZBkxbyl73dV5URHwvZA78CqVXWJggaofAy2JfZBf1GCoUQfNCyN0TAJaEnnsLn9ea6d2wLtDAataFtxGyFQJwZBWajQOiIwtidXqliCFV8haorHgfE4ahdbpO5n7oUZD&limit=25&since=1397743992&__previous=1";
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you give more information about which fields you're seeing and which ones you expect?

Comment: ok i will add both data please help me

Comment: Hello @jesse Rusak sir  i have edit please give me solution is any hope for my problem i have add both data in facebook graph api and xcode return result 
please Help

Comment: Are you sure you've asked for the required permissions to view the user's posts? The post you're seeing in Xcode is public, as opposed to the friends-only post on the web.

Comment: i have post a wall on feed by me i want to seeing this post 
i am using me?fields=posts on graph api on facebook developer account i am able to every my latest post wall,picture but this graph api i am using in iphone app that not return as same to same data this is diffrent data show what shoud i do

Answer (score 0):

The posts list is divided into several pages, and you only got the first page. To get all the posts, use the URL in `results.posts.paging.next`.

You can use this [FBSDKGraphRequest paging extension](https://gist.github.com/yonat/0a37ccb89adfc8f92d740e8549093d14) to do that for you.